# What's the fastest way to take Mean of a Tensor in given slot?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, tensors

One should expect that the implementation of the built-in function `Mean` was quick. However, as I recently observed, this is not true at all, in particular for matrices. Just compare `Mean` to the following simple function:

```
mean[A_?TensorQ] := ConstantArray[1./Length[A], Length[A]].A
```

A test with a decently sized matrix:

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4000, 5000}];
a = Mean[A]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
b = mean[A]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
Max[Abs[a - b]]

(* 0.220566 *)
(* 0.008163 *)
(* 1.71738*10^-16 *)
```

Wow, for a built-in function, this is *really, really* bad. For higher rank matrices, this gap is not as pronounced but it is still there:

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {400, 500, 300}];
a = Mean[A]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = mean[A]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[a - b]]

(* 0.110258 *)
(* 0.024915 *)
(* 2.22045*10^-16 *)
```

Okay, for the first (and also for the last slot), there is this workaround by using `Dot`. What about a slot in between? E.g. how to compute `Total[A,{2}]/Dimensions[A][[2]]` as fast as possible?

PS.: The same mess appears with `Total`, a function that I usually value quite high, in particular since `Total` allows for level specs.

Comment: Using exact values in the targets and in the function reverses the performance dramatically. Hypothesis: I'd venture the dot with machine precision takes a path using Intel MKL, while Mean/Total, being built to handle general forms (e.g. symbolic, mixed) dont.

Comment: @ciao You are totally right about exact arithmetic. I really aim for `PackedArrays`. What I wanted to point out is that it might be a good idea to overload `Mean` for `PackedArrays` to something that actually uses Intel MKL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a compiled version of [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total) that is faster for intermediate levels:

```
total[d_, l_] := With[
    {o = ConstantArray[1., Dimensions[d][[l]]], n = Length@Dimensions@d-l+1},
    Switch[l,
        1, o.d,

        Length@Dimensions@d, d.o,

        _,
        With[{fc = Compile[{{data, _Real, n}}, o.data, RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}]},
            fc[d]
        ]
    ]
]
```

For your higher rank example:

```
d = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {400, 500, 300}];

r1 = total[d, 2]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Total[d, {2}]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 == r2
```

> {0.0632, Null}
>
> {0.11, Null}
>
> True

I will leave the modification to compute the mean instead to you.

Comment: Shiny! I wasn't aware that we can control the threading level of listable compiled functions this way. Thank you, this answers also several further questions! =o)

Answer (score 3):

First, don't use `TensorQ`.  It is undocumented and may change in the future.  The documented function to use is `ArrayQ`.  Second, here an arbitrary-rank version of your function,

```
mean[A_?ArrayQ, slot_] :=  With[
   {d = Part[Dimensions[A], slot]}, 
   ConstantArray[1./d, d].Transpose[A, 1 <-> slot]
]
```

Unfortunately, it is slower than `Total` for higher-rank, because the cost of rearranging memory is too high.  I suspect that Carl's approach is probably the best you can do, but I can't immediately prove that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on `ArrayQ`. And you are right, transposing is not an option...