# Implementing a planetary terrain generation algorithm

Tags: graphics3d, random, generative-art

From [this (now deleted) question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158832/38205) I found [this site](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/noise) where the author discusses a simple technique for random terrain generation on a sphere.

The method discussed is as follows:

- start with a collection of points and its center, $c$
- take some random perturbation $p\in(0, 1)$ and offset, $\lambda $, (I missed this originally) and random vector $v$
- find the hemispheres created by the plane through $c+\lambda v$ normal to $v$, call them $h_1$ and $h_2$
- for every point in $h_1$, move it $p$ percent further away from $c$, for every point in $h_2$ move it $p$ percent closer to $c$

How can I implement this? (bonus points for efficiency)

Comment: related: [Generate landscape by cutting a plane in 3d](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136592/5478)

Comment: @Kuba good point. I had the implementation, then thought to ask the question (because who knows what I'm missing in mine). Next time I'll give it a day or so.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark ah yeah the poster of that question deleted it. I'll note that.

Comment: This is a classic: [Complex planetary surface creation with perlin noise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/examples/complexplanet/index.html)

Comment: @RobC interesting. I'd love to see a Mathematica implementation of that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here my two cents. I observed that the major part of the computation is about multiplication. Hence I transformed to logarithms such that we can use summations which can be executed efficiently with `Dot`. Moreover, I replaced the `If` clause with the listable `Sign`. Thus, the working horse function looks like this:

```
getErodedPoints =  Compile[
  {{pt, _Real, 1}, {center, _Real, 1}, {logp, _Real, 1}, {offsets, _Real, 1}, {v, _Real, 2}},
  center + (pt - center) Exp[logp.Sign[v.(pt - center)-offsets]],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
];
```

By the way, here an implementation for a random uniform distribution of points on the 3-sphere:

```
RandomUnitVector3D[n_] := With[{
   cf = Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}},
     {Cos[X[[2]]] Power[1 - X[[1]]^2, 1/2], Power[1 - X[[1]]^2, 1/2] Sin[X[[2]]], X[[1]]},
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, Parallelization -> True
     ]},
  cf[Transpose[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n], RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, n]}]]
  ]
```

After these preparations, we can generate our new class-M-planet as follows:

```
R = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0000001];
pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
steps = 25000;
logp = RandomReal[{-.0001, .0001}, steps];
v = RandomUnitVector3D[steps];
center = ConstantArray[0., 3];
offsets = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, steps];
npts = getErodedPoints[pts, center, logp, offsets,v];
r = Sqrt[Dot[npts^2,ConstantArray[1., {3}]]];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[],
  GraphicsComplex[
   npts, 
   Polygon[Developer`ToPackedArray[MeshCells[R, 2][[All, 1]]]],
   VertexColors -> ColorData["AlpineColors"] /@ (Rescale[r]^2)
   ]
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Boxed -> False
 ]
```

[image]

The call to `getErodedPoints` with a sphere of about 200000 points and with 25000 steps takes about 10 seconds on my machine.

Comment: You can even just do `Rescale[r]`. The `MinMax[r]` and `{0, 1}` are implicit. I think it was common enough in the plotting routines they just made it default.

Comment: @b3m2a1 You're right. This might be quite useful in the future... Thank's for the hint!

Comment: As noted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13041), there is a relatively simple method for generating uniformly-distributed random unit vectors: `v = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {steps, 3}];`. (But, since it goes inside a `Sign[]` anyway, you can omit normalization.) Also, `r = Sqrt[Total[npts^2, {2}]];` is much more compact.

Comment: @J.M. In a perfect world, `Sqrt[Total[npts^2, {2}]]` would be faster than `Sqrt[Dot[npts^2, ConstantArray[1., {3}]]]`. But since this is not the case at the moment (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158345), I do not rely any more on the depth specs of `Total`. `Normalize` is pretty slow, but using the normal distribution for the (unscaled) directions is a very good idea!

Answer (score 24):

I have a basic implementation of this which I use with the output of `DiscretizeGraphics`:

```
sphTerrainGenCore =
  Compile[
   {
    {tcoords, _Real, 2},
    {coords, _Real, 2},
    {center, _Real, 1},
    {perturbation, _Real},
    {offset, _Real}
    },
   MapIndexed[
    center +
      (coords[[#2[[1]]]] - center)*
       (1 + perturbation*If[#[[1]] > center[[1]] + offset, 1, -1]) &,
    tcoords
    ]
   ];
sphTerrainGenStep[{coords_, cells_, center_}, {normal_, perturbation_,
     offset_}] :=
  {
   sphTerrainGenCore[
    RotationTransform[{normal, {1, 0, 0}}, center]@coords,
    coords,
    center,
    perturbation,
    offset
    ],
   cells,
   center
   };
sphTerrainGenStep[
   {coords_, cells_, center_},
   steps_Integer,
   perturbationBounds : {_, _} : {.00001, .001},
   offsetBounds : {_, _} : {0, .1}
   ] :=
  Fold[
   sphTerrainGenStep[#, #2] &,
   {coords, cells, center},
   Transpose@{
     RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {steps, 3}],
     RandomReal[perturbationBounds, steps],
     RandomReal[offsetBounds, steps]
     }
   ];
sphTerrainGenStep[{r_?RegionQ, center_},
  steps_Integer,
  perturbationBounds : {_, _} : {.00001, .001},
  offsetBounds : {_, _} : {0, .1}
  ] :=
 With[{ret =
    sphTerrainGenStep[{
      MeshCoordinates[r],
      MeshCells[r, All],
      center
      },
     steps,
     perturbationBounds
     ]
   },
  {
   MeshRegion[ret[[1]], ret[[2]]],
   ret[[3]]
   }
  ]
```

I then initialize a `MeshRegion` to work with:

```
Options[sphTerrainGenInit] =
  Options@DiscretizeGraphics;
sphTerrainGenInit[
   pointNum : _Integer : 10000,
   center : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} : {0, 0, 0},
   rad : _Real : 1,
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  {DiscretizeGraphics[Ball[center, rad], ops], center};
Options[sphTerrainGen] =
  Options@sphTerrainGenInit;
sphTerrainGen[
  steps : _Integer : 100,
  perturbationBounds : {_, _} : {.00001, .001},
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 With[{base = sphTerrainGenInit[ops]},
  MeshRegion @@ Take[sphTerrainGenStep[base, steps], 2]
  ]
```

I've then got a basic caching generator and a plotting function:

```
Options[planetTerrainDataCached] =
  Options[sphTerrainGenInit];
planetTerrainDataCached[0, stepSize_Integer, ops_] :=

  planetTerrainDataCached[0, stepSize, ops] =
   sphTerrainGenInit[FilterRules[{ops}, Options@sphTerrainGenInit]];
planetTerrainDataCached[step_Integer, stepSize_Integer, ops_] :=

  planetTerrainDataCached[step, stepSize, ops] = 
   sphTerrainGenStep[planetTerrainData[step - 1, stepSize, ops], 
    stepSize];
Options[planetTerrainData] =
  Options[planetTerrainDataCached];
planetTerrainData[step_Integer, stepSize : _Integer : 100, 
   ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

  With[{o = 
     SortBy[Flatten@
       FilterRules[{ops}, Options@planetTerrainDataCached], First]},
   planetTerrainDataCached[step, stepSize, o]
   ];
Options[planetTerrain] =
  Options[planetTerrainData];
planetTerrain[step_Integer, stepSize : _Integer : 100, 
  ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

 planetTerrainData[step, stepSize, ops][[1]]

Options[planetTerrainPlot] =
  Join[
   Options[SliceDensityPlot3D],
   Options[planetTerrain]
   ];
planetTerrainPlot[i_Integer, stepSize : _Integer : 100, 
   ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  planetTerrainPlot[
   planetTerrain[i, stepSize, 
    FilterRules[{ops}, Options[planetTerrain]]],
   ops
   ];
planetTerrainPlot[reg_?RegionQ, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

 With[{rb = RegionBounds[reg]},
  SliceDensityPlot3D[
   Norm[{x, y, z}],
   reg,
   {x, rb[[1, 1]], rb[[1, 2]]},
   {y, rb[[2, 1]], rb[[2, 2]]},
   {z, rb[[3, 1]], rb[[3, 2]]},
   Sequence @@
     FilterRules[
      {
       ops,
       ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors",
       Boxed -> False,
       Axes -> False
       },
      Options[SliceDensityPlot3D]
      ] // Evaluate
   ]
  ]
```

Put this all together:

```
planetTerrainPlot[1, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001]
```

[image: planet]

We can also animate the steps of the algorithm:

```
slides1 =
  Map[planetTerrainPlot[#, 1, ImageSize -> 250] &, Range@25];
slides1 // ListAnimate
```

[image: anim]

We can really see how it's a sort-of addition of hemispheres.

Finally we can go to large numbers of steps and see just how craggy it becomes:

```
planetTerrainPlot[25, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001]
```

[image: big steps]

That's after ~25,000 steps. We could always decrease the cragginess some by playing with the `perturbationBounds` parameter I defined in my step function, though.

To get more visible terrain contrast, we can take one of our less-craggy meshes and scale its points based on the histogram of `Norm` values we have:

```
Rescale[Norm /@ 
   MeshCoordinates[
    planetTerrain[3, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001]]] // SmoothHistogram
```

[image: hist]

This might lead us to do something like this:

```
regs = {
     #,
     MeshRegion[
      MapThread[
       Which[
         #2 > .99, #3*#,
         #2 < .98, #4*#,
         True, #
         ] &,
       {
        MeshCoordinates[#],
        Rescale[Norm /@ MeshCoordinates[#]],
        RandomReal[{1.01, 1.03}, Length@MeshCoordinates[#]],
        RandomReal[{.97, .98}, Length@MeshCoordinates[#]]
        }],
      MeshCells[#, All]
      ]
     } &@
   planetTerrain[3, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001];
regs // Map[planetTerrainPlot] // Row
```

[image: craggled]

At a minimum, the method described by the author in the link can be implemented like this

Answer (score 9):

What I have is a vastly simpler version, with the slight tweak of possibly using smaller perturbations of the spherical mesh.

To simplify things, start from a discretized (unit) ball (centered on the origin) and extract the points and polygons:

```
m0 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.02}];
pts = MeshCoordinates[m0]; polys = MeshCells[m0, 2];
```

(You can do scaling and translation later if you need it.)

From here, the code to perform the slicing + scaling is remarkably simple (I take only a few steps `n` and use an exaggerated value for `h` for now so that the slicing action is clearly seen):

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42];
            With[{n = 10, h = 0.01},
                 Do[v = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]; p = RandomReal[h];
                    pts += p Sign[pts.v] pts, {n}]];]

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], GraphicsComplex[pts, polys]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: first few steps]

With `n = 1000` and `h = 0.002` we see something much more craggy:

[image: some fake planet]

Coloring can be done like so:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
            GraphicsComplex[pts, polys, 
                            VertexColors -> (ColorData["AlpineColors"] /@
                                             Rescale[Norm /@ pts])]}]
```

[image: fake alpine planet]

Alternatively, replace `pts` with `MeshCoordinates[m0]` if you only want to use the perturbations for coloring:

[image: just the coloring]

---

A compiled version goes like this:

```
makePlanet = Compile[{{msh, _Real, 2}, {h, _Real}, {n, _Integer}},
                     Module[{pts = msh, p, v},
                            Do[v = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 3]; p = RandomReal[h];
                               pts += p Sign[pts.v] pts, {n}];
                            pts]];
```

which should be faster for a larger number of iterations:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; pp = makePlanet[pts, 0.0005, 10000];
            Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
                        GraphicsComplex[pp, polys, 
                                        VertexColors -> (ColorData["AlpineColors"] /@
                                                         Rescale[Norm /@ pp])]},
                       Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: really craggy planet]